# jQuery generate breadcrumbs from url?

Tags: jquery, breadcrumbs

Is there a way of getting jQuery to generate breadcrumbs on a page from the url?

So if the site url was:
mysite.com/sec1/sec2/page

The breadcrumbs would be something like:
Home > Sec1 > Sec2 > Page

Thanks

Comment: jQuery won't do it for you, but it's trivial to code.

Comment: Code with what? Do you mean server side code like PHP?

Comment: @jldn: In JavaScript, among other things. You should rather do stuff like this with server side languages, though. No need to bother the client for this.

Comment: In an ideal world im sure your right, but I dont know how to program it server side and jQuery is normally much easier to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create an array you can use to generate breadcrumbs.

```
var here = location.href.split('/').slice(3);

var parts = [{ "text": 'Home', "link": '/' }];

for( var i = 0; i < here.length; i++ ) {
    var part = here[i];
    var text = part.toUpperCase();
    var link = '/' + here.slice( 0, i + 1 ).join('/');
    parts.push({ "text": text, "link": link });
}
```

Though, I really think you should be handling this at the server side!

Answer (score 3):

Full Javascript function to display breadcrumbs from page url based on Bill Criswell's answer

```
  function getBreadcrumbs() {
    const here = location.href.split('/').slice(3);
    // console.log(here)
    const parts = [{"text": 'Home', "link": '/'}];
    // console.log(parts)

    for (let i = 0; i < here.length; i++) {
        const part = here[i];
        // console.log(part)
        const text = decodeURIComponent(part).toUpperCase().split('.')[0];
        // console.log(text)
        const link = '/' + here.slice(0, i + 1).join('/');
        console.log(link)
        parts.push({"text": text, "link": link});
        // console.log(parts)
    }
    return parts.map((part) => {
        return "<a href=\"" + part.link + "\">" + part.text + "</a>"
    }).join('<span style="padding: 5px">/</span>')
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getBreadcrumbs();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'mysite.com/sec1/sec2/page'; // = location.href
var parts = url.split('/');
parts[0] = 'Home';
var breadcrumb = parts.join(' &gt; ');
$('#breadcrumb').html(breadcrumb);
```

Comment: You have to be careful with location.href. You will also get the http:// which will shit on your split. `location.href.split('/').slice(3)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
splitted_url = document.url.split('/');
```

Will give you an array containing each directory, then you can access them like `splitted_url[0]`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have any unique URL parsing abilities aside from what JavaScript itself provides. You can get the URL path with:

```
var path = location.pathname;
```

Then, you can get the parts of the path with:

```
var parts = path.split('/');
```

Then, just loop through the parts and generate your breadcrumb HTML as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const titleizeWord = (str) => `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`;
const kebabToTitle = (str) => str.split("-").map(titleizeWord).join(" ");

const toBreadcrumbs = (pathname, { rootName = "Home", nameTransform = s=> s} = {}) =>
    pathname
        .split("/")
        .filter(Boolean)
        .reduce(
            (acc, curr, idx, arr) => {
                acc.path += `/${curr}`;
                acc.crumbs.push({
                    path: acc.path,
                    name: nameTransform(curr),
                });

                if (idx === arr.length - 1) return acc.crumbs;
                else return acc;
            },
            { path: "", crumbs: [{ path: "/", name: rootName }] },
        );

toBreadcrumbs("/team-members/joe-schmoe", { nameTransform: kebabToTitle });
/*
[
  { path: "/", name: "Home" },
  { path: "/team-members", name: "Team Members },
  { path: "/team-members/joe-schmoe", name: "Joe Schmoe" },
]
*/
```