# Is there a way to generate breadcrumbs from given url in spredsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to extract (where possible) or generate (where breadcrumbs not available) breadcrumbs from url in spreadsheets.
So for pages that have it, I'm just using a IMPORTXML (refined by case)

```
=TEXTJOIN(" > ", 1,importxml(A66,"//*[@id='breadcrumbs']/div/div/ul",1))
```

[Page Example](https://www.nea.gov.ph/ao39/about-us/charter/ra-9136)

But I'm trying to see if there's a fast way to generate them from given page where not available (like this [one](https://www.whitehouse.gov/about-the-white-house/presidents/george-washington/), but where the navigation path might not be visible in link either) . I was looking into this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445240/jquery-generate-breadcrumbs-from-url). Is there a way to use it in google aps script?

Comment: I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That would be difficult since you don't specifically know what to find. Have you thought of a logic/algorithm that will define how will it be found? If not, then that is near impossible. You could try and read about [`XMLService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) and use it to navigate the site.

The problem is that websites doesn't have a standard on the structure of it and will vary from each other. Unless you are viewing sites from a single domain (which is also a bit difficult), i don't think it would be that easy and direct to create a general script for all sites.

Comment: I'm wandering more about url's that don't have the path in the link, so like this one https://www.sss.gov.ph/sss/appmanager/viewArticle.jsp?page=sscommission > where the breadcrumb is not clear - but you have to manually inspect HTML elements to see which divs are open and so on